# How to index array of objects in elastic search using rest API in Java

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm using ES 7.5.1 for storing data, with Rest API (Spring-boot).
It's working fine with a single object but when I tried to pass an array of objects it's throwing bad request or not acceptable error(406).

Code:

```
List<UserBean> objectList;
String response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:9200/employeedata/users", objectList, String.class);
```

Comment: this information provided is not sufficient for helping, please give share more information.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I'm new to elastic search please specify what information is required.

Comment: Which version of elastic are you using?

Comment: ES version is 7.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can index bulk data into elastic using **RestHighLevelClient**

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>${elastic.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>${elastic.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Configuration :

```
@Bean
protected RestHighLevelClient createInstance() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", "9200", "http")));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOG.error("Error while creating RestHighLevelClient", e);
    }
    return restHighLevelClient;
}
```

Usage :

```
@Autowired
private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

@Override
public void storeBulkDataInElastic(List<UserBean> dataBeanList) throws IOException
{
    BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    dataBeanList.forEach(data -> {
        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("ElasticIndex", "ElasticType", "ElasticId").source(objectMapper.convertValue(data, Map.class));
        bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);
    });

    restHighLevelClient.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Bulk API. [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/docs-bulk.html)
This API accepting arrays of objects in JSON (NDJSON) structure.

> Performs multiple indexing or delete operations in a single API call. This reduces overhead and can greatly increase indexing speed.